# Jquery: Smooth resize when changing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

My page layout is 3 horizontal DIVS. The middle DIV is going to have content loaded into it. I want the DIV to do a smooth height resize to the appropriate size (like using `animate`) then fade in the content.

This is what I have at the moment

```
<div id='a'></div>
<div id='b'>foo</div>
<div id='c'></div>

$( '#a ').fadeOut().innerHtml('bar').hide().fadeIn()
```

This gives me close to what I want, but looks pretty rough

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and also have jQueryUI accessible

**Elaboration**

Currently, the middle DIV will fadeout, then (as there is no content) will disappear. When the new content is added, it instantly resizes and fades in the new content.

What I want to happen is the content fades out and keeps the height. When the new content is added, I want the div to resize to the appropriate height and THEN fade in the content

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "looks pretty rough"? What do you want changing?

Comment: I updated the question to further explain what I want to happen. Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to the following. Note that you have used `innerHtml` on a JQuery object, the correct syntax is `html`. Also, you've unnecessarily called `hide` after you've set the content, but the item should already be hidden because you have called `fadeOut`.

Try this:

```
$( '#a ').fadeOut().html('bar').fadeIn()
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SmZgw/1/**

Comment: thanks for the answer, not sure really why I had the hide() in there anyway. Lets say it was $( '#a ').fadeOut().html('foo<br/>bar<br/>').fadeIn() Is there a way to make the resize animated?

Comment: Yeah here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/SmZgw/2/ that animates the height, same can be applied for width